# AutoMapper - Map a complex object using naming conventions without providing inner mappings

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two complex objects that have exactly the same properties.

Now with `AutoMapper`, I usually will need to do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjA, ObjB>();
```

But if one of the objects has a complex inner object, Ill  need to map it too:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjAInner, ObjBInner>();
```

Now I have a large object that expands all the time.
I don't want to maintain the `CreateMap` calls each time I add a complex inner object to the main object.

Now I can probably solve this with a recursive reflection on the main object and map all the types but I'd prefer not to do that.

Is there anyway I can tell `AutoMapper` to Create a full recursive map(also for inner types) on a complex object?

Something like this:

```
 Mapper.CreateFullMapOnIdenticalObjectsWithInnerTypes<ObjA, ObjB>();
```

**Edit:**

Here's an example:

two identical classes with a different namespace:

```
namespace NameSpace1
{
    public class Obj1
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public InnerObj1 InnerObj1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerObj1
    {
        public string StrInner1 { get; set; }
        public int NumInner1 { get; set; }

        public AnotherInnerObj1 AnotherInnerObj1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnotherInnerObj1
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace NameSpace2
{
    public class Obj1
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
        public int Num { get; set; }
        public InnerObj1 InnerObj1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerObj1
    {
        public string StrInner1 { get; set; }
        public int NumInner1 { get; set; }

        public AnotherInnerObj1 AnotherInnerObj1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnotherInnerObj1
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Create a mock `NameSpace1.Obj1`:

```
        public static NameSpace1.Obj1 Create()
        {
            return new NameSpace1.Obj1
            {
                Num = 10,
                Str = "Obj1",
                InnerObj1 = new NameSpace1.InnerObj1
                {
                    NumInner1 = 11,
                    StrInner1 = "InnerObj1",
                    AnotherInnerObj1 = new NameSpace1.AnotherInnerObj1
                    {
                        Str = "AnotherInnerObj1"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

This is what I would like:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<NameSpace1.Obj1, NameSpace2.Obj1>();
    var obj1 = Create();
    var obj2 = Mapper.Map<NameSpace2.Obj1>(obj1);
```

But this will throw an exception since I need to define inner mappings. This will work:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<NameSpace1.Obj1, NameSpace2.Obj1>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<NameSpace1.InnerObj1, NameSpace2.InnerObj1>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<NameSpace1.AnotherInnerObj1, NameSpace2.AnotherInnerObj1>();
    var obj1 = Create();
    var obj2 = Mapper.Map<NameSpace2.Obj1>(obj1);
```

Comment: do you mean that you don't want to keep adding the new inner properties to objB when objA expands ?

Comment: No.. The two objects will be identical. I dont want to add Mappings on future properties..

Comment: But if both objects are identical,  it means that both have same properties ans same properties type,  so mapping objectA to objectB will be enough,  because automapper will use reflection to match properties.

Comment: It works until he gets to a complex method and then he needs the inner mapping.

Comment: Can you show us the case that automapper needs the inner mapping to map? Add the class definition to your question.

Comment: @Omar.Alani - I've added an example. Thank you!!!